# Get latest stable helm release

Tags: shell, kubernetes-helm

Is there a shell command to get the latest stable helm release .

For kubernetes we have something like this

curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
wget -qO- https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/releases | sed -n '/Latest release<\/a>/,$p' | grep -oE 'v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' |head -1
```

Result:

```
v2.8.2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not longer work with Helm 3

Answer (score 2):

And, for those without wget:

```
HVER=$(curl -sSL https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/releases | sed -n '/Latest release<\/a>/,$p' | grep -oE 'v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | head -1)

echo $HVER
```

Result (currently):

`v2.9.1`

To download the gz that contains the latest Helm executable:

**Linux**

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-${HVER}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

**OSX**

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-${HVER}-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
```

**Windows (bash ell)**

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-${HVER}-windows-amd64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

if in-case you use `Dockerfile` & `Linux`

```
RUN wget "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-$(wget -qO- https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/releases | sed -n '/Latest release<\/a>/,$p' | grep -oE 'v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' |head -1)-linux-amd64.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, OSX, and Windows targets:

```
HELM_INSTALL_DIR=[‘desired path’]
USE_SUDO=[‘true’|’false’]
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash
```

Other install options: [Helm Install Documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/)

[Recommend migration away from V2.x as soon as you can.](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it for v2:

```
curl -L0 "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz" | tar xzO linux-amd64/helm > /usr/local/bin/helm
```

And for v3:

```
curl -L0 "https://get.helm.sh/helm-v${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz" | tar xzO linux-amd64/helm > /usr/local/bin/helm
```

Do not forget to `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/helm` afterwards.